# Не вызываются иконки из svg спрайта

Tags: html, css, svg, icon, svg-спрайт

Не вызывается иконка из спрайта
Оригинальная svg иконка которая сгенерированная программой Avacode

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><defs><path id="qq8ea" d="M460 1193.998a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 0 2.004h2.999V1199a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 2.003 0v-2.998H468a1.002 1.002 0 1 0 0-2.004h-3V1191a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-2.002 0v2.998zm3.998 12.002c-6.064 0-10.998-4.934-10.998-10.998 0-2.941 1.145-5.705 3.222-7.781a10.92 10.92 0 0 1 7.776-3.223 10.93 10.93 0 0 1 7.781 3.223 10.936 10.936 0 0 1 3.222 7.781c0 2.937-1.145 5.7-3.222 7.775a10.93 10.93 0 0 1-7.781 3.223z"/></defs><g><g transform="translate(-452 -1183)"><use fill="#a86ac7" xlink:href="#qq8ea"/><use fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#a86ac7" stroke-miterlimit="50" xlink:href="#qq8ea"/></g></g></svg>
```

А здесь созданный мною спрайт, который пока содержит ту самую одну иконку

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
            <defs>
                <symbol id="plus" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M460 1193.998a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 0 2.004h2.999V1199a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 2.003 0v-2.998H468a1.002 1.002 0 1 0 0-2.004h-3V1191a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-2.002 0v2.998zm3.998 12.002c-6.064 0-10.998-4.934-10.998-10.998 0-2.941 1.145-5.705 3.222-7.781a10.92 10.92 0 0 1 7.776-3.223 10.93 10.93 0 0 1 7.781 3.223 10.936 10.936 0 0 1 3.222 7.781c0 2.937-1.145 5.7-3.222 7.775a10.93 10.93 0 0 1-7.781 3.223z"/>
                </symbol>
            </defs>
        </svg>
```

И вот так я пробую вызывать иконку с этого спрайта

```
<svg>
            <g transform="translate(-452 -1183)"><use fill="#a86ac7" xlink:href="#plus"></use></g>
        </svg>
```

Но почему-то не вызывается иконка в чем проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Теория

Если спрайт, в котором находится иконка является отдельным файлом, то необходимо сначала добавить этот файл в HTML

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/svgdefs.svg">
  Your  browser does not support SVG 
</object>
```

И только потом вызывать иконку по `ID` из этого спрайта:

```
<svg>
            <g transform="translate(-452 -1183)"><use fill="#a86ac7" xlink:href="svgdefs.svg#plus"></use></g>
        </svg>
```

### Note

Экспериментальные технологии `Chrome` в этом вызове допускают не указывать имя файла, в котором хранится иконка, но для более полной поддержки всеми браузерами лучше указывать имя файла

### Практика

Теги `<symbol id="plus">` c `ID` используются по двум показаниям:

- svg код внутри этих тегов скрывается до вызова командой `<use>` и в
  одном файле спрайте можно поместить несколько иконок с разными `ID`
- Каждому тегу `<symbol id="icon2" viewBox="0 0 24 24">` можно
  присвоить свой `viewBox`, который позволяет отдельно масштабировать
  каждую иконку.

Ниже код вашей иконки. Аккуратно убрал лишнее.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">

 <path id="qq8ea" d="M460 1193.998a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 0 2.004h2.999V1199a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 2.003 0v-2.998H468a1.002 1.002 0 1 0 0-2.004h-3V1191a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-2.002 0v2.998zm3.998 12.002c-6.064 0-10.998-4.934-10.998-10.998 0-2.941 1.145-5.705 3.222-7.781a10.92 10.92 0 0 1 7.776-3.223 10.93 10.93 0 0 1 7.781 3.223 10.936 10.936 0 0 1 3.222 7.781c0 2.937-1.145 5.7-3.222 7.775a10.93 10.93 0 0 1-7.781 3.223z"/>

 <g transform="translate(-452 -1183)">
  <use fill="#a86ac7" stroke="#a86ac7" xlink:href="#qq8ea"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Окружаем код `<symbol id="plus">`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24"  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<symbol  id="plus" >
 <path id="qq8ea" d="M460 1193.998a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 0 2.004h2.999V1199a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 2.003 0v-2.998H468a1.002 1.002 0 1 0 0-2.004h-3V1191a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-2.002 0v2.998zm3.998 12.002c-6.064 0-10.998-4.934-10.998-10.998 0-2.941 1.145-5.705 3.222-7.781a10.92 10.92 0 0 1 7.776-3.223 10.93 10.93 0 0 1 7.781 3.223 10.936 10.936 0 0 1 3.222 7.781c0 2.937-1.145 5.7-3.222 7.775a10.93 10.93 0 0 1-7.781 3.223z"/>
 </defs>
 <g transform="translate(-452 -1183)">
  <use fill="#a86ac7" stroke="#a86ac7" xlink:href="#qq8ea"/>
  </g> 
 </symbol>  
</svg>
```

Как и ожидалось всё скрывается до вызова с помощью `<use>`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24"  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 
<symbol  id="plus">
 <path id="qq8ea" d="M460 1193.998a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 0 2.004h2.999V1199a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 2.003 0v-2.998H468a1.002 1.002 0 1 0 0-2.004h-3V1191a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-2.002 0v2.998zm3.998 12.002c-6.064 0-10.998-4.934-10.998-10.998 0-2.941 1.145-5.705 3.222-7.781a10.92 10.92 0 0 1 7.776-3.223 10.93 10.93 0 0 1 7.781 3.223 10.936 10.936 0 0 1 3.222 7.781c0 2.937-1.145 5.7-3.222 7.775a10.93 10.93 0 0 1-7.781 3.223z"/>
 
 <g transform="translate(-452 -1183)">
  <use fill="#a86ac7" stroke="#a86ac7" xlink:href="#qq8ea"/>
  </g> 
 </symbol>  
 
</svg> 

<svg>
 <use xlink:href="#plus" />
</svg>
```

**Теперь можно вызывать эту иконку сколько угодно раз**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24"  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
 <defs>
<symbol  id="plus">
 <path id="qq8ea" d="M460 1193.998a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 0 2.004h2.999V1199a1.002 1.002 0 0 0 2.003 0v-2.998H468a1.002 1.002 0 1 0 0-2.004h-3V1191a1.002 1.002 0 0 0-2.002 0v2.998zm3.998 12.002c-6.064 0-10.998-4.934-10.998-10.998 0-2.941 1.145-5.705 3.222-7.781a10.92 10.92 0 0 1 7.776-3.223 10.93 10.93 0 0 1 7.781 3.223 10.936 10.936 0 0 1 3.222 7.781c0 2.937-1.145 5.7-3.222 7.775a10.93 10.93 0 0 1-7.781 3.223z"/>
 
 <g transform="translate(-452 -1183)">
  <use fill="#a86ac7" stroke="#a86ac7" xlink:href="#qq8ea"/>
  </g> 
 </symbol>  
 </defs>
</svg> 

<svg>
 <use xlink:href="#plus" />
<use xlink:href="#plus" transform="scale(2)" x="15" /> 
<use xlink:href="#plus" transform="scale(3)" x="30" />
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Я пока не отделял спрайт в отдельный файл, потому что он в одно html файле с вызовом не работает

Comment: @LiEm Если вы работаете на локалке в `Chrome`, то иконки на локалке в этом браузере из файла не вызываются - известный баг  В любом случае лучше всегда указывать имя файла, чтобы не мучиться потом в поисках багов

Comment: Не в локалке дело, а в svg где-то ошибка зарыта я вызывал простые фигуры в виде круга и все отлично вызывается

Comment: @LiEm сейчас сделаю update в вашем примере с вашей иконкой

Comment: с нетерпением жду, надеюсь поможете

Comment: @LiEm придется немного подождать, дело действительно в иконке, что-то вы намудрили :)

Comment: @LiEm готово. Надеюсь это вам поможет

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @LiEm Да не за что. Практический совет, когда будете рисовать свои иконки постарайтесь сделать так, чтобы не было внутри кода `transform` translate/ То есть нужно выбирать размер документа при рисовании чуть чуть больше размера иконки и строго рисовать внутри него, не перемещать иконку, не масштабировать при рисовании. А на этапе освоения svg лучше брать профессиональные иконки