# SVG иконки спрайта работают в Firefox но не работают в Chrome

Tags: html5, svg, google-chrome, svg-спрайт, background-image

прошу о помощи. `svg` иконки из спрайта отлично отображается в `Firefox`

```css
{
   background-image: url(/assets/img/sprite/global.svg#icon--upload);
   background-size: 18px 18px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 0% 50%;
}
```

Но не отображается в Хроме. Вы с таким сталкивались? 2 дня на это убил...

Код SVG спрайта:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>symbol{display:none}symbol:target{display:inline}</style>



<!-- HEADER -->
<symbol id="icon--upload" viewBox="0 0 91.8 92.6" fill="#fff">
<path d="M46.3,3.6c-23.5,0-42.5,19-42.5,42.5s19,42.5,42.5,42.5c23.5,0,42.5-19,42.5-42.5S69.8,3.6,46.3,3.6zM72.8,52.9H53v19.8c0,2-1.6,3.6-3.6,3.6h-6.2c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6V52.9H19.8c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6v-6.2c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h19.8  V19.7c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h6.2c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v19.8h19.8c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v6.2C76.4,51.2,74.8,52.9,72.8,52.9z"/>
</symbol>
<!-- HEADER -->



<!-- GLOBAL -->
<symbol id="icon--help" viewBox="0 0 40.124 40.124" fill="#5f4781">
<path d="M19.938,12.141c1.856,0,2.971,0.99,2.971,2.66c0,3.033-5.414,3.869-5.414,7.55c0,0.99,0.648,2.072,1.979,2.072    c2.042,0,1.795-1.516,2.538-2.6c0.989-1.453,5.6-3,5.6-7.023c0-4.361-3.897-6.188-7.858-6.188c-3.773,0-7.24,2.692-7.24,5.725c0,1.237,0.929,1.887,2.012,1.887C17.525,16.225,15.979,12.141,19.938,12.141z"/>
<path d="M22.135,28.973c0-1.393-1.145-2.537-2.537-2.537s-2.537,1.146-2.537,2.537c0,1.393,1.145,2.537,2.537,2.537S22.135,30.366,22.135,28.973z"/>
<path d="M40.124,20.062C40.124,9,31.124,0,20.062,0S0,9,0,20.062s9,20.062,20.062,20.062S40.124,31.125,40.124,20.062zM2,20.062C2,10.103,10.103,2,20.062,2c9.959,0,18.062,8.103,18.062,18.062c0,9.959-8.103,18.062-18.062,18.062C10.103,38.124,2,30.021,2,20.062z"/>
</symbol>

<symbol id="icon--checkmark" viewBox="0 0 512 512" fill="#fff">
<path d="M461.6,109.6l-54.9-43.3c-1.7-1.4-3.8-2.4-6.2-2.4c-2.4,0-4.6,1-6.3,2.5L194.5,323c0,0-78.5-75.5-80.7-77.7c-2.2-2.2-5.1-5.9-9.5-5.9c-4.4,0-6.4,3.1-8.7,5.4c-1.7,1.8-29.7,31.2-43.5,45.8c-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.4-2,2.1c-1.2,1.7-2,3.6-2,5.7c0,2.2,0.8,4,2,5.7l2.8,2.6c0,0,139.3,133.8,141.6,136.1c2.3,2.3,5.1,5.2,9.2,5.2c4,0,7.3-4.3,9.2-6.2L462,121.8c1.2-1.7,2-3.6,2-5.8C464,113.5,463,111.4,461.6,109.6z"/>
</symbol>

<symbol id="icon--dropdown" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="#606060">
<polygon points="47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25"/>
</symbol>
<!-- GLOBAL -->



</svg>
```

**Update 08.02.2019 г.**

У меня получилось заставить Хром работать если использовать "g" вместо "symbol", а затем используя "view". Пока крайне мере так он их уже отоброжает в Chrome и в Firefox. Т.е вот так:

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  


  <view id="icon--upload" viewBox="0 0 91.8 92.6"/>
  <view id="icon--help" viewBox="0 0 40.124 40.124"/>
  <view id="icon--checkmark" viewBox="0 0 512 512"/>
  <view id="icon--dropdown" viewBox="0 0 50 50"/>


    <!-- HEADER -->
    <g id="icon--upload" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M46.3,3.6c-23.5,0-42.5,19-42.5,42.5s19,42.5,42.5,42.5c23.5,0,42.5-19,42.5-42.5S69.8,3.6,46.3,3.6zM72.8,52.9H53v19.8c0,2-1.6,3.6-3.6,3.6h-6.2c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6V52.9H19.8c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6v-6.2c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h19.8  V19.7c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h6.2c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v19.8h19.8c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v6.2C76.4,51.2,74.8,52.9,72.8,52.9z"/>
    </g>
    <!-- HEADER -->



    <!-- GLOBAL -->
    <g id="icon--help" fill="#5f4781">
    <path d="M19.938,12.141c1.856,0,2.971,0.99,2.971,2.66c0,3.033-5.414,3.869-5.414,7.55c0,0.99,0.648,2.072,1.979,2.072    c2.042,0,1.795-1.516,2.538-2.6c0.989-1.453,5.6-3,5.6-7.023c0-4.361-3.897-6.188-7.858-6.188c-3.773,0-7.24,2.692-7.24,5.725c0,1.237,0.929,1.887,2.012,1.887C17.525,16.225,15.979,12.141,19.938,12.141z"/>
    <path d="M22.135,28.973c0-1.393-1.145-2.537-2.537-2.537s-2.537,1.146-2.537,2.537c0,1.393,1.145,2.537,2.537,2.537S22.135,30.366,22.135,28.973z"/>
    <path d="M40.124,20.062C40.124,9,31.124,0,20.062,0S0,9,0,20.062s9,20.062,20.062,20.062S40.124,31.125,40.124,20.062zM2,20.062C2,10.103,10.103,2,20.062,2c9.959,0,18.062,8.103,18.062,18.062c0,9.959-8.103,18.062-18.062,18.062C10.103,38.124,2,30.021,2,20.062z"/>
    </g>

    <g id="icon--checkmark" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M461.6,109.6l-54.9-43.3c-1.7-1.4-3.8-2.4-6.2-2.4c-2.4,0-4.6,1-6.3,2.5L194.5,323c0,0-78.5-75.5-80.7-77.7c-2.2-2.2-5.1-5.9-9.5-5.9c-4.4,0-6.4,3.1-8.7,5.4c-1.7,1.8-29.7,31.2-43.5,45.8c-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.4-2,2.1c-1.2,1.7-2,3.6-2,5.7c0,2.2,0.8,4,2,5.7l2.8,2.6c0,0,139.3,133.8,141.6,136.1c2.3,2.3,5.1,5.2,9.2,5.2c4,0,7.3-4.3,9.2-6.2L462,121.8c1.2-1.7,2-3.6,2-5.8C464,113.5,463,111.4,461.6,109.6z"/>
    

    <symbol id="icon--dropdown" fill="#606060">
    <polygon points="47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25"/>
   
    <!-- GLOBAL -->
    </svg>
```

Но у меня однозначно проблемы с viewBox. Потому что иконки начинают появляться в разных местах на сайте и друг на друге (если спрайт открыть в отдельной вкладке). У всех иконок viewBox разный. Я не понимаю какой viewBox нужно давать самому спрайту, какие иконкам? И нужно ли добавлять width="" и height=""? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: про `viewBox` почитайте здесь, всё просто и на пальцах объяснено А пока посмотрю ваш код https://svg-art.ru/?p=5

Comment: Мне кажеться я попробовал все варианты. У меня не получаеться, они все лежат как хотят в спрайте, а насколько я понимаю они должны все отдельно друг от друга быть.

Answer (score 5):

Если иконки SVG расположены на `localhost`, то есть на вашем ПК, то они не будут отображаться в `Chrome`. Увы..
 Настраиваете своё приложение в `FF`, а потом уже загрузите на сервер и у вас заработает и в  `Chrome`

Добавление иконок в HTML с помощью `<object>`

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/934756/28748

Посмотрите ещё выборку [вопросов-ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) по спрайтам с иконками svg. Кажется уже все варианты рассмотрели и у ребят рано или поздно всё получилось.

Comment: Александр, я находил такое решение проблемы на английском стаке. Я переносил все на продакшн, но увы иконки не появляются, они замечательно работают через "use xlink:href=.." но через background-image или просто background в CSS в хроме не в какую. В фф все отлично. Через base6 Сейчас еще раз попробовал, подумал, может про кэш забил. Но нет. Ctrl+f5 тоже не помогло.

Через base64 в CSS работают, но у меня большой готовый спрайт чтобы сейчас заниматься переделкой всех иконок в base64 (плюс захламлять css не хочеться) а background-image в хроме не работает :(

Comment: @SoreThursday ну а почему обязательно добавлять иконки, посредством background, это самый плохой способ, который пошел от `css-tricks` Ведь есть же другие способы добавления. <object> например. Грузите один раз файл в HTML, а потом вызываете через `use` в любом месте Html и в производительности выиграете Ещё учтите, преобразовав в base64, вы не сможете стилизовать иконки

Comment: Потому что необходимо использовать в псеудо css класах :before и :after.

Comment: @SoreThursday а что вы хотите добавлять к svg с помощью  `:before и :after`.?

Comment: Иконку checkbox. Александр я внизу дополнил ответ, как получилось добиться вывода в Хроме, но проблема с viewBox. Вы могли подправить как этот код должен работать?

Comment: Нет к самой SVG, а используя sprite.svg через background-image иконку checkbox. В цсс там зайдествованы :before и :after.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на вторую часть вопроса **update 08. 02. 2019 г.**

Методом тыка вы верно определили, что теги `<symbol>` скрывают иконки в спрайте.
Это делается для того, чтобы загрузить спрайт (файл *.svg) в `HTML`, а затем вызывать нужную иконку по её `ID` c помощью команды `<use>`
Ссылки, как это реализуется я уже дал в первом ответе. 
Пока продемонстрирую, что у вас получилось.

Добавил стиль в шапку svg файла, чтобы была видна граница svg.
  Добавил `width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512"`

Иконки у вас имеют разные размеры и разные viewBox

```css
 svg {
 stroke:black;
 fill:none;
 
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="border:1px solid red;">

  <view id="icon--upload" viewBox="0 0 91.8 92.6"/>
  <view id="icon--help" viewBox="0 0 40.124 40.124"/>
  <view id="icon--checkmark" viewBox="0 0 512 512"/>
  <view id="icon--dropdown" viewBox="0 0 50 50"/> 


    <!-- HEADER -->
    <g id="icon--upload" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M46.3,3.6c-23.5,0-42.5,19-42.5,42.5s19,42.5,42.5,42.5c23.5,0,42.5-19,42.5-42.5S69.8,3.6,46.3,3.6zM72.8,52.9H53v19.8c0,2-1.6,3.6-3.6,3.6h-6.2c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6V52.9H19.8c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6v-6.2c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h19.8  V19.7c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h6.2c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v19.8h19.8c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v6.2C76.4,51.2,74.8,52.9,72.8,52.9z"/>
    </g>
    <!-- HEADER -->



    <!-- GLOBAL -->
    <g id="icon--help" fill="#5f4781">
    <path d="M19.938,12.141c1.856,0,2.971,0.99,2.971,2.66c0,3.033-5.414,3.869-5.414,7.55c0,0.99,0.648,2.072,1.979,2.072    c2.042,0,1.795-1.516,2.538-2.6c0.989-1.453,5.6-3,5.6-7.023c0-4.361-3.897-6.188-7.858-6.188c-3.773,0-7.24,2.692-7.24,5.725c0,1.237,0.929,1.887,2.012,1.887C17.525,16.225,15.979,12.141,19.938,12.141z"/>
    <path d="M22.135,28.973c0-1.393-1.145-2.537-2.537-2.537s-2.537,1.146-2.537,2.537c0,1.393,1.145,2.537,2.537,2.537S22.135,30.366,22.135,28.973z"/>
    <path d="M40.124,20.062C40.124,9,31.124,0,20.062,0S0,9,0,20.062s9,20.062,20.062,20.062S40.124,31.125,40.124,20.062zM2,20.062C2,10.103,10.103,2,20.062,2c9.959,0,18.062,8.103,18.062,18.062c0,9.959-8.103,18.062-18.062,18.062C10.103,38.124,2,30.021,2,20.062z"/>
    </g>

    <g id="icon--checkmark" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M461.6,109.6l-54.9-43.3c-1.7-1.4-3.8-2.4-6.2-2.4c-2.4,0-4.6,1-6.3,2.5L194.5,323c0,0-78.5-75.5-80.7-77.7c-2.2-2.2-5.1-5.9-9.5-5.9c-4.4,0-6.4,3.1-8.7,5.4c-1.7,1.8-29.7,31.2-43.5,45.8c-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.4-2,2.1c-1.2,1.7-2,3.6-2,5.7c0,2.2,0.8,4,2,5.7l2.8,2.6c0,0,139.3,133.8,141.6,136.1c2.3,2.3,5.1,5.2,9.2,5.2c4,0,7.3-4.3,9.2-6.2L462,121.8c1.2-1.7,2-3.6,2-5.8C464,113.5,463,111.4,461.6,109.6z"/>
    </g>

    <g id="icon--dropdown" fill="#606060">
    <polygon points="47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25"/>
    </g>
    <!-- GLOBAL -->
    </svg>
```

так как у всех иконок разный `viewBox` очень проблематично настроить их все в один размер.

**Покажу практический способ, как разнокалиберные иконки привести к одному размеру.**

Но лучше сразу подбирать иконки одного размера с одинаковым `viewBox` и не иметь эту головную боль/

Красная рамка это граница SVG `512x512px`

Теперь спрячем иконки (обернем в теги `<symbol>`) и будем их вызывать по одной с помощью команды `<use>`

- Вызываем иконку `icon--upload` и уменьшаем её в два раза

`<use xlink:href="#icon--upload" transform="scale(0.5) translate(0 0)" />`

```css
 svg {
 stroke:black;
 fill:none;
 
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="border:1px solid red;">

 <!--  <view id="icon--upload" viewBox="0 0 91.8 92.6"/>
  <view id="icon--help" viewBox="0 0 40.124 40.124"/>
  <view id="icon--checkmark" viewBox="0 0 512 512"/>
  <view id="icon--dropdown" viewBox="0 0 50 50"/> -->
   <rect width="52" height="52" stroke-width="2" stroke="blue" />

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <symbol id="icon--upload" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M46.3,3.6c-23.5,0-42.5,19-42.5,42.5s19,42.5,42.5,42.5c23.5,0,42.5-19,42.5-42.5S69.8,3.6,46.3,3.6zM72.8,52.9H53v19.8c0,2-1.6,3.6-3.6,3.6h-6.2c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6V52.9H19.8c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6v-6.2c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h19.8  V19.7c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h6.2c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v19.8h19.8c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v6.2C76.4,51.2,74.8,52.9,72.8,52.9z"/>
    </symbol>
    <!-- HEADER -->



    <!-- GLOBAL -->
    <symbol id="icon--help" fill="#5f4781">
    <path d="M19.938,12.141c1.856,0,2.971,0.99,2.971,2.66c0,3.033-5.414,3.869-5.414,7.55c0,0.99,0.648,2.072,1.979,2.072    c2.042,0,1.795-1.516,2.538-2.6c0.989-1.453,5.6-3,5.6-7.023c0-4.361-3.897-6.188-7.858-6.188c-3.773,0-7.24,2.692-7.24,5.725c0,1.237,0.929,1.887,2.012,1.887C17.525,16.225,15.979,12.141,19.938,12.141z"/>
    <path d="M22.135,28.973c0-1.393-1.145-2.537-2.537-2.537s-2.537,1.146-2.537,2.537c0,1.393,1.145,2.537,2.537,2.537S22.135,30.366,22.135,28.973z"/>
    <path d="M40.124,20.062C40.124,9,31.124,0,20.062,0S0,9,0,20.062s9,20.062,20.062,20.062S40.124,31.125,40.124,20.062zM2,20.062C2,10.103,10.103,2,20.062,2c9.959,0,18.062,8.103,18.062,18.062c0,9.959-8.103,18.062-18.062,18.062C10.103,38.124,2,30.021,2,20.062z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon--checkmark" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M461.6,109.6l-54.9-43.3c-1.7-1.4-3.8-2.4-6.2-2.4c-2.4,0-4.6,1-6.3,2.5L194.5,323c0,0-78.5-75.5-80.7-77.7c-2.2-2.2-5.1-5.9-9.5-5.9c-4.4,0-6.4,3.1-8.7,5.4c-1.7,1.8-29.7,31.2-43.5,45.8c-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.4-2,2.1c-1.2,1.7-2,3.6-2,5.7c0,2.2,0.8,4,2,5.7l2.8,2.6c0,0,139.3,133.8,141.6,136.1c2.3,2.3,5.1,5.2,9.2,5.2c4,0,7.3-4.3,9.2-6.2L462,121.8c1.2-1.7,2-3.6,2-5.8C464,113.5,463,111.4,461.6,109.6z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon--dropdown" fill="#606060">
    <polygon points="47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25"/>
    </symbol>
    <!-- GLOBAL -->  
 
 <use xlink:href="#icon--upload" transform="scale(0.5) translate(0 0)" />
    </svg>
```

- Вызываем иконку `icon--help` увеличиваем её и сдвигаем на 1px вправо
  и вниз

`<use xlink:href="#icon--help" transform="scale(1.2) translate(1 1)" />`

```css
svg {
 stroke:black;
 fill:none;
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="border:1px solid red;">

 <!--  <view id="icon--upload" viewBox="0 0 91.8 92.6"/>
  <view id="icon--help" viewBox="0 0 40.124 40.124"/>
  <view id="icon--checkmark" viewBox="0 0 512 512"/>
  <view id="icon--dropdown" viewBox="0 0 50 50"/> -->
   <rect width="52" height="52" stroke-width="2" stroke="blue" />

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <symbol id="icon--upload" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M46.3,3.6c-23.5,0-42.5,19-42.5,42.5s19,42.5,42.5,42.5c23.5,0,42.5-19,42.5-42.5S69.8,3.6,46.3,3.6zM72.8,52.9H53v19.8c0,2-1.6,3.6-3.6,3.6h-6.2c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6V52.9H19.8c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6v-6.2c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h19.8  V19.7c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h6.2c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v19.8h19.8c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v6.2C76.4,51.2,74.8,52.9,72.8,52.9z"/>
    </symbol>
    <!-- HEADER -->



    <!-- GLOBAL -->
    <symbol id="icon--help" fill="#5f4781">
    <path d="M19.938,12.141c1.856,0,2.971,0.99,2.971,2.66c0,3.033-5.414,3.869-5.414,7.55c0,0.99,0.648,2.072,1.979,2.072    c2.042,0,1.795-1.516,2.538-2.6c0.989-1.453,5.6-3,5.6-7.023c0-4.361-3.897-6.188-7.858-6.188c-3.773,0-7.24,2.692-7.24,5.725c0,1.237,0.929,1.887,2.012,1.887C17.525,16.225,15.979,12.141,19.938,12.141z"/>
    <path d="M22.135,28.973c0-1.393-1.145-2.537-2.537-2.537s-2.537,1.146-2.537,2.537c0,1.393,1.145,2.537,2.537,2.537S22.135,30.366,22.135,28.973z"/>
    <path d="M40.124,20.062C40.124,9,31.124,0,20.062,0S0,9,0,20.062s9,20.062,20.062,20.062S40.124,31.125,40.124,20.062zM2,20.062C2,10.103,10.103,2,20.062,2c9.959,0,18.062,8.103,18.062,18.062c0,9.959-8.103,18.062-18.062,18.062C10.103,38.124,2,30.021,2,20.062z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon--checkmark" fill="#fff">
    <path  vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  d="M461.6,109.6l-54.9-43.3c-1.7-1.4-3.8-2.4-6.2-2.4c-2.4,0-4.6,1-6.3,2.5L194.5,323c0,0-78.5-75.5-80.7-77.7c-2.2-2.2-5.1-5.9-9.5-5.9c-4.4,0-6.4,3.1-8.7,5.4c-1.7,1.8-29.7,31.2-43.5,45.8c-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.4-2,2.1c-1.2,1.7-2,3.6-2,5.7c0,2.2,0.8,4,2,5.7l2.8,2.6c0,0,139.3,133.8,141.6,136.1c2.3,2.3,5.1,5.2,9.2,5.2c4,0,7.3-4.3,9.2-6.2L462,121.8c1.2-1.7,2-3.6,2-5.8C464,113.5,463,111.4,461.6,109.6z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon--dropdown" fill="#606060" >
    <polygon points="47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25"/>
    </symbol>
    <!-- GLOBAL -->  
 
 <use xlink:href="#icon--help" transform="scale(1.2) translate(1 1)" />
    </svg>
```

- Вызываем иконку icon--checkmark уменьшаем её в 10 раз и сдвигаем на
  1px вправо и вниз

```css
svg {
 stroke:black;
 fill:none;
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="512" height="512" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="border:1px solid red;">

 <!--  <view id="icon--upload" viewBox="0 0 91.8 92.6"/>
  <view id="icon--help" viewBox="0 0 40.124 40.124"/>
  <view id="icon--checkmark" viewBox="0 0 512 512"/>
  <view id="icon--dropdown" viewBox="0 0 50 50"/> -->
   <rect width="52" height="52" stroke-width="2" stroke="blue" />

    <!-- HEADER -->
    <symbol id="icon--upload" fill="#fff">
    <path d="M46.3,3.6c-23.5,0-42.5,19-42.5,42.5s19,42.5,42.5,42.5c23.5,0,42.5-19,42.5-42.5S69.8,3.6,46.3,3.6zM72.8,52.9H53v19.8c0,2-1.6,3.6-3.6,3.6h-6.2c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6V52.9H19.8c-2,0-3.6-1.6-3.6-3.6v-6.2c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h19.8  V19.7c0-2,1.6-3.6,3.6-3.6h6.2c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v19.8h19.8c2,0,3.6,1.6,3.6,3.6v6.2C76.4,51.2,74.8,52.9,72.8,52.9z"/>
    </symbol>
    <!-- HEADER -->



    <!-- GLOBAL -->
    <symbol id="icon--help" fill="#5f4781">
    <path d="M19.938,12.141c1.856,0,2.971,0.99,2.971,2.66c0,3.033-5.414,3.869-5.414,7.55c0,0.99,0.648,2.072,1.979,2.072    c2.042,0,1.795-1.516,2.538-2.6c0.989-1.453,5.6-3,5.6-7.023c0-4.361-3.897-6.188-7.858-6.188c-3.773,0-7.24,2.692-7.24,5.725c0,1.237,0.929,1.887,2.012,1.887C17.525,16.225,15.979,12.141,19.938,12.141z"/>
    <path d="M22.135,28.973c0-1.393-1.145-2.537-2.537-2.537s-2.537,1.146-2.537,2.537c0,1.393,1.145,2.537,2.537,2.537S22.135,30.366,22.135,28.973z"/>
    <path d="M40.124,20.062C40.124,9,31.124,0,20.062,0S0,9,0,20.062s9,20.062,20.062,20.062S40.124,31.125,40.124,20.062zM2,20.062C2,10.103,10.103,2,20.062,2c9.959,0,18.062,8.103,18.062,18.062c0,9.959-8.103,18.062-18.062,18.062C10.103,38.124,2,30.021,2,20.062z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon--checkmark" fill="#fff">
    <path  vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"  d="M461.6,109.6l-54.9-43.3c-1.7-1.4-3.8-2.4-6.2-2.4c-2.4,0-4.6,1-6.3,2.5L194.5,323c0,0-78.5-75.5-80.7-77.7c-2.2-2.2-5.1-5.9-9.5-5.9c-4.4,0-6.4,3.1-8.7,5.4c-1.7,1.8-29.7,31.2-43.5,45.8c-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.4-2,2.1c-1.2,1.7-2,3.6-2,5.7c0,2.2,0.8,4,2,5.7l2.8,2.6c0,0,139.3,133.8,141.6,136.1c2.3,2.3,5.1,5.2,9.2,5.2c4,0,7.3-4.3,9.2-6.2L462,121.8c1.2-1.7,2-3.6,2-5.8C464,113.5,463,111.4,461.6,109.6z"/>
    </symbol>

    <symbol id="icon--dropdown" fill="#606060" >
    <polygon points="47.25,15 45.164,12.914 25,33.078 4.836,12.914 2.75,15 25,37.25"/>
    </symbol>
    <!-- GLOBAL -->  
 
 <use xlink:href="#icon--checkmark" transform="scale(0.1) translate(1 1)" />
    </svg>
```

> Повторюсь, чтобы не было головной боли по масштабированию и
>   позиционированию иконок выбирайте их одинакового размера, в сети их
>   миллионы.

Примечание

*Для последнего примера - `id="icon--checkmark"` применено свойство  `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`, так как происходит уменьшение иконки в 10 раз и линии становятся очень тонкими `0.1px`. К сожалению это работает, - сохранение ширины линий при масштабировании, только в SVG.*

**Этот способ добавления `svg` с помощью `<object>` работает во всех современных браузерах включая `IE11`, `Edge`**

Comment: @SoreThursday Если ответы были полезны, не забудьте отметить их плюсами и галочкой. Мы все  здесь отвечаем на вопросы абсолютно бесплатно, поэтому хотелось бы видеть ответную, положительную реакцию.

Comment: Александр я use то у меня нету проблем, проблемы именно с backround-image потому что нужно вставить в псеудо CSS классы :before :after :(

Comment: @SoreThursday вы сказали, что решили проблемы со вставкой, убрав `<symbol>`, просили пояснить, что делать с `viewBox` в вашем довольно сложном случае, я ответил на вопросы? Хочется мучиться с background способом, не принимая мои рекомендации с `<object>`, ну это ваш выбор. Добавлю лишь, что потом, когда вам захочется сделать иконки анимированными или ещё, что-то другое, вы просто не сможете в силу, того,что это теоретически невозможно. при добавлении через `background`

Comment: Александр, а можно взять иконки с разными значениями viewBox и сделать его им всем одинаковый? Если да то каким способом?

Comment: @SoreThursday я же показал способ. Выбираете самый большой viewBox, который есть в иконках и ставите его в шапку svg файла  `viewBox="0 0 512 512"` затем подгоняете каждую иконку по размерам **`scale`** и позиционируете  **`translate`**  Например в коде иконки <path transform="scale(0.5) translate(10 10)" d="M цифры" А какие проблемы у вас сразу найти одинаковые иконки по размерам и не мучиться вот так

Comment: Все что скачиваю все время разные viewBox использую такие ресурсы как iconfinder и flaticon. А где вы находите иконки с одинаковым viewbox?

Comment: @SoreThursday нахожу у себя на компьютере :) В свое время накачал из разных мест. Основное правило, чем короче код, значит иконка сделана профессинально.  Например гугловские наборы иконок очень хорошие, сейчас поищу ссылку

Comment: @SoreThursday вот почитайте мой ответ по гугловским иконкам https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/770153/28748 понравится, не забудьте поблагодарить автора плюсиком и вот ссылка на гугловские иконки они все одинакового размерв и качества  https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=alarm_add&style=baseline

Comment: Я все время плюсики ставлю. Как же это все достало.. неужели нету какогото способа/программы куда бы ты закидывал иконки с разным viewBox  а он тебе на выходе делал одинаковый viewbox для всех (понятно что квадрный, для промоугольных такое не подойдет)?

Comment: @SoreThursday неужели трудно скачать качественные иконки, положить на свой ПК и пользоваться, поищите ссылку, там же, на скачивания всего набора иконок они на все случаи жизни. А такой программы нет, чтобы разные иконки, нарисованные кривыми руками приводить к одним размерам. Поглубже разберетесь с SVG и поймёте почему очень трудно написать такую программу :).

Comment: Трудно когда нужно очень специфичные и уникальные иконки. Но помойму урааааа, я нашел сервис который позволит мне сделать идентичный viewBox и затем через "g" выводить их в Chrome и Firefox. Когда сделаю новый спрайт и подключу все, то отпишу :))))

Comment: @SoreThursday так поделитесь ссылочкой  на сервис,который нашли:)

Comment: Ссылочка https://icomoon.io/app/ но я дополню как все делать в своем вопросе, правильно? или Мне ответ писать?

Comment: @SoreThursday конечно лучше ответ написать

Answer (score 0):

Немного дополню комментатора выше. Можно во время разработки использовать локальный сервер, например `Open Server`.

Также предсказываю будущий вопрос, почему не работает в IE(какой-то там версии), используйте полифилл svg4everybody

Comment: В Опере кстати тоже не работает. Только в Firefox.